# How can i get the batch quantity in the cart page?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $cartItems  = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        }
        $batch_qty = $product->getBatchQty();
```

Through this code i can get the batch quantity, same way i need to get the batch quantity in the cart page how can i get this ?

In the cart page i can see the

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
```

also product name `echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName())` why i am not getting batch quantity, i give `$_item->getBatchQty();` but it is nothing retrieves.

Comment: did you try putting  $batch_qty = $product->getBatchQty(); into the foreach loop?

Comment: @cleong that code is on another page, Which is giving exact result, but in cart page is already looped result are getting, but how can i get the batch qty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$batchQty = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId())->getBatchQty()
```

Using this method I got the batch quantity.